# How do I use Sonargraph SonarQube plugin?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have a couple of questions about the Sonargraph *SonarQube* plugin. The first is, **is the plugin free**? When downloading the plugin from the dashboard the license is of a type called Apache2, which I think is free. Is this actually the case?

The second question is how do I use the plugin? I found some instructions on the developers' website but they all pertained to scanning via Maven. Here is the link to said instructions:https://www.hello2morrow.com/products/sonargraph/sonar **Is it possible to scan with sonar-runner**? If so, how can I view the results on the dashboard?

Thank-you for reading this.

Regards,

Comment: Could you edit your question to provide a link to the documentation you found?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should directly contact Hello2morrow to get answers to your question, because Sonargraph is a commercial product.

Comment: Thank-you I may try this. I thought it was free software because the plugin has an Apache 2 license.

Answer (score 0):

I am one of the developers working for hello2morrow and can answer your question:

The Sonargraph plugin for SonarQube is free.
But you need a commercial license for Sonargraph's build component (Maven or Ant) to generate the XML report that the plugin processes.
The plugin is a free add-on for our customers who want to integrate the Sonargraph metrics into SonarQube.